# Thermoelectric Seebeck Crystalline Structure

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity, thermoelectricity

Recently reading about Crystalline Structure in metals and other forms of doping. Being that thermal energy has so called phonons could it be that crystals in metal having an effect like that for ex. AM Radio and crystal used in that to power the setup. It is said that too much imperfection in metal can be bad for tensile strength make it brittle to say but in something like TEG Crystalline Structure could be good in thermoelectric? Thinking years ago seeing a raw semiconductor piece used to make chips left over chunk learning grown from a crystal. Fascinated me reading recently about crystals in Seebeck advancements and thinking about thermal energy and how a crystal AM radio works. How big of a effect could the Crystalline Structure of metal make the Seebeck effect even better with the idea/concept of the crystal AM radio in thinking too?

Comment: I’m really struggling to follow your logic. Linking thermoelectric materials to AM radio crystals is not clear to me.

Comment: Upon reading scientific articles talk about crystals improving Seebeck effect. AM crystal radio came to mind being that heat has energy in it as well. Perhaps not just the metal aspects but addition of the crystalline aspect in addition to. Thought crossed my mind.

Comment: Further refreshing memory learning more on phonons... https://www.britannica.com/science/phonon

Comment: Interesting doing more research on growing copper or nickel crystals supposedly crystal growth is fast at say low temperature absolute zero? If so perhaps superconducting crystal growth? Metal is said to be superconducting at absolute zero but at that temp crystal growth is fast also if one was to make copper or nickel crystals as examples how phonons would act if crystal structure was pure? Room temperature superconducting?